# using camera to focus on object after translations and rotations in processing 3.0

Tags: processing

I have a program where a box ( player ) can land on the ground ( environment ), move and jump around. In the process of trying to make the boxes forward direction independent from the environment I used a couple or translations and rotations. this works fine for the boxes movement but now i do not know the coordinates of the box to use the camera function to focus on it.

```
 void setup() {
   size(600,600,P3D);
   PVector eye = new PVector(0,0,0);
   PVector translations = new PVector(0,0,0);
    background(200);
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    rotateZ(mouseX/(width/PI));
    //ground would be drawn here
    translate(0,0,-400);
    translate(50, 100 ,490);
    rotateZ(-mouseX/(width/PI));
    box(150);
    translations.add(0,0,0);//translations occurring from rotations and translation
    eye.add(translations);
    eye.add(500, 1000, 500); //translate the eye away from the point its looking at 

  camera(eye.x, eye.y, eye.z, translations.x, translations.y, translations.z, 0, 0, -1);
  eye.mult(0);
  translations.mult(0);
 }
```

How can I find the position of the box after the translations? I know that the use of sin and cos is necessary but i cannot for the life of me get an algorithm that works perfectly.

edit: I changed the code to be complete and verifiable

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Note that this should not be your full program, but should be a simple example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: apologise. I have reuploaded some code that is both verifiable and complete

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Maybe you're looking for the `screenX()` and `screenY()` or `modelX()` and `modelY()` functions?

Comment: Yes, The modelX and modelY functions are exactly what i was looking for. I have since created my own functions to mathematically find these coordinates but In the future I will be glad to use the inbuilt functions. There isn't any links in the "camera" reference on these functions and i feel that they should go hand in hand since the camera doesn't take into consideration translations.